# Cordova - Can static HTML/JS/CSS be encrypted in the distributable device specific files

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

When I built an APK file using cordova build, it bundles all the HTML/JS/CSS3 static files into the APK file in simple plain/text format. This way anyone will be able to easily use this code and create copy of my app. Is there any way to encrypt these files?

Comment: Apart from obfuscation of your code, I do not think there's any other way. And, may I ask what is your application about? Usually the business logic stays on the server as a service, so there is no major revelation of your logic.

Comment: I have all logic on client. I don't have any server. Coz I'm fetching from external public feeds and websites only.

Comment: Even when I obfuscate code, all files can be simply used as is to make other build with different app name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% foolproof way for this, I could think of a solution where you will need a web server running a script for authenticating and then providing the core Javascript or a URL for the same in response. And you could save it locally for future use.

To keep the access restricted to your application, you will have to get the app's package name and then only provide the response. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406793/phonegap-how-to-get-name-of-app-within-app) should help you to get your package's name.

In addition, you could add some logic on your server as well as your Javascript where you will generate a random unique string based on the timespan and add it to authentication process' parameters. And obfuscating all of your packaged JS in the apk will make it difficult for anyone to get your whole logic.

Comment: I can decompile your apk and find the way you obfuscate code. Apk file can download from CH play directly by any tools. I think you don't care about that. Anyone an get your code, but they not get your idea and so on.

Comment: I did care about all of the issues, I am totally aware of it; that is why we need all of the measures to avoid access to our core logic.

Comment: If your core logic add into client side then anyone can get it. Even if you have server side to authenticate or so on. Then they still get your logic step by step in debug tools (Chrome, Safari,..). If your app require authenticate from server then you don't care about it. User have account then they can do anything. I was download many app (hybrid), install in emulator and seeing what things app get from my device.

Comment: Ideally, if the application is debuggable, Play Store won't accept the apk. So wouldn't debug tools be useless? Then the only option would be to understand the obfuscated code and find out the right parameters for server-side authentication.